# What are the steps to simplify the following equation (with simplified version included)

Tags: polynomials, fractions

This is part of a question asking to find the differential of a polynomial fraction. I have already taken the derivative using quotient and chain rule, and this is where I am up to.

Rather than go through the entire question (I have been told this is too confusing for readers in previous questions), I will simply show the area where I am stuck.

I need to know how to simplify :
$$\frac{\sqrt{2x-x^2}-\frac{-x+1}{\sqrt{2x-x^2}}x}{(\sqrt{2x-x^2})^2}$$

to :
$$\frac{x}{(2x-x^2)^{3/2}}$$

Any help with this would be very much appreciated , exam is tomorrow .

P.S. If users would prefer me to write out the full question, just ask and I will. I am still learning to write the perfect question.

Comment: not clear what you mean by $2x^{\_2}$

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out, it has been corrected .

Comment: This has nothing whatsoever to do with [division-algebras](http://math.stackexchange.com/tags/division-algebras/info). Please read tag wikis before using a tag you are unfamiliar with.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$\frac{\sqrt{2x-x^2}-\frac{-x+1}{\sqrt{2x-x^2}}x}{(\sqrt{2x-x^2})^2}=\frac{\frac{2x-x^2}{\sqrt{2x-x^2}}-\frac{-x+1}{\sqrt{2x-x^2}}x}{(\sqrt{2x-x^2})^2}=\frac{\frac{2x-x^2+x^2-x}{\sqrt{2x-x^2}}}{(\sqrt{2x-x^2})^2}$$

Can you continue from here?

Comment: I am currently working through this part, During the transition from the 1st part to the 2nd part I would expect the right numerator to be multiplied by the left denominator, why is this not so ?

Comment: I am only expanding the first expression with the denominator from the second to have a common denominator.

Comment: Okay im really sorry to sound like an idiot, I thought that the process was 1. multiply denominators to get common denominator, 2. left numerator x right denominator, 3. right numerator x left denominator. I see that you have done step 1 and 2, but it looks as if you have skipped 3 and starting simplifying the top without multiplying the right numerator by the left denominator. Could you please explain what I am missing here ?

Comment: left denominator is 1.

Comment: Hasn't the left denominator already been converted to sqrt(2x-x^2) after step 1?

Comment: After step 1 you allready have the same denominators. The x belongs to the (-x+1).

Answer (score 0):

Look at it as $(\sqrt A-(-x+1)x/\sqrt A)/(\sqrt A)^2$ with $A=2 x-x^2.$

Assuming $A> 0$ we have $(\sqrt A)^2=A=2 x-x^2,$ which,so far,is a simpler denominator. (Actually the notation $\sqrt A$ should only be used when $A\geq 0.$ And we must have $A\ne 0$ else we have a denominator $0$.)

Now get rid of that pesky minus-sign between the two terms of the numerator by re-writing the numerator as $\sqrt A+(x-1)x/\sqrt A$ and re-write this as $\sqrt A+(x^2-x)/\sqrt A .$

The big step now is to multiply both the numerator and denominator by $\sqrt A$ to remove the occurrence of a denominator $\sqrt A$  within the numerator of the whole expression. This gives us $((\sqrt A)^2+\;x^2-x)/ (A\sqrt A).$

Once again we have $(\sqrt A)^2=A$ so we can write the numerator as $A+(x^2-x).$ But what is $A$? It's $2 x-x^2.$ So the numerator is $(2 x-x^2)+(x^2-x).$ Now look for a re-grouping or for terms that cancel out: $2 x-x^2+x^2-x=2 x-x=x $ is  now the numerator.

So we obtain $x/(A\sqrt A)=$ $x/(A^{3/2})=$ $x/(2 x-x^2)^{3/2}.$

We can also at this point divide both the numerator and denominator by $\sqrt x$ to obtain $\sqrt x/(2-x)^{3/2}$ and, if we like, write this as $(x/(2-x)^3)^{1/2}$.